# Importing 3rd-party libraries in angular2

Tags: angular

I might be missing something obvious here, but how am I supposed to 
import a third-party library that doesn't export anything.

I tried all of the following

```
import '../bower_components/asn1js/asn1';
import {ASN1} from '../bower_components/asn1js/asn1';
import ASN1 from '../bower_components/asn1js/asn1';
```

Neither of which worked.

If you take a look at the [asn1.js](https://github.com/lapo-luchini/asn1js/blob/master/asn1.js) file you can see in the end the following:

```
// export globals
if (typeof module !== 'undefined') { module.exports = ASN1; } else { window.ASN1 = ASN1; }
```

It seems that it is trying to export itself. I'm not familiar with this so could you explain me:

- What decides whether module is undefined? where should it be defined?
- If it is undefined or api doesn't use export, how can I import/use it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wrapping 3rd party components in angular2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36984382/wrapping-3rd-party-components-in-angular2)

Answer (score 0):

Since it is exporting a global object you don't need to import it.
If anything what you would be importing would be it's TypeScript.definition file but I am not sure there is one yet.

So you should just try the following.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'Component',
  directives: [],
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <h3>Component</h3>
  `
})
export class Componentimplements OnInit{    
  constructor(private _asn1 : window.ASN1 || ASN1){

  }

  ngOnInit(){}
}
```