# wrapping 3rd party components in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to use 3rd party ui elements/components in my angular2 app like e.g. [spin.js](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/). To use this library I would have to directly access the DOM which is not really the way it should be done in angular2 (for several reasons like for example server-side rendering):

```
var target = document.getElementById('foo')
var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
```

Is there any advice on how to deal with such 3rd party libraries in angular2? Or is direct DOM manipulation the only way for now?

Comment: Can you share your plunker demo because even i am trying to build a directive...  so that i can use your code as a reference and proceed...Please sir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would wrap it into a custom directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[spinner]'
})
export class SpinnerDirective {
  constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef.nativeElement) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(this.elementRef);
  }
}
```

and use it this way:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  template: `
    <span spinner>...</span>
  `,
  directives: [ SpinnerDirective ]
})
export class SomeComponent {
  (...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, except that I had to use elementRef.nativeElement inside the spin method

Comment: My component decorator doesn't take a directives argument (using TypeScript).  Is this a limitation of TypeScript or is there a different official way to add directives to a component?